# Spring MVC: list of checkboxes not returned to controller on POST

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, checkbox, controller

**Why doesn't the server see my list of filled checkboxes?**

This question seems to be here asked many times, but the details are so different for each requester that it seems a different answer is needed each time.  Here is my story.

These are my data-bearing classes.  The Offer contains a list of Filter objects in the filter attribute:.

```
public class Offer implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Long id = null;

    @Column(name="title")
    private String title = null;
    [snip]

    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "offer_filter", 
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "offer_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, 
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "filter_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) })
    private List<Filter> filters;

    [snip]
}

public class Filter implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    @Length(max=100)
    @Column(name="text")
    private String text;

    [snip]

    @Transient
    private boolean owned = false;

    [snip]
}
```

The simple controller sends the offerEdit.jsp page, with a fully-populated Offer object. The object contains a list of Filters. Because of the owned attribute, only one of the three Filters is pre-checked. This simulates my eventual plan, where the list of Filters is the whole universe and what the Offer owns is a subset.

Note the annotations, that the Offer has the filter list going to the web page but doesn't see it coming back.

```
public class OfferController {
    [snip]

    @RequestMapping(value = "/edit", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getEdit(@RequestParam("id") Long id, Model model, HttpSession session) {
        Offer offerAttribute = offerService.get(id);

        // At this point, offerAttribute.filters has three elements.
        // Mockup -- tells web page that only the middle one of the three Filters should be checked.
        List<Filter> filters = offer.getFilters();
        Filter filter = filters.get(1);
        filter.setOwned(true);

        model.addAttribute("offerAttribute", offerAttribute);

        return "offer/offerEdit";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/edit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String postEdit(@RequestParam("id") Long id, @Valid @ModelAttribute("offerAttribute") Offer offerAttribute, BindingResult result, HttpSession session, Model model) {

        // At this point, offerAttribute.filters is null.
        if(result.hasErrors()) {
            result.reject("offer.invalidFields");

            return "offer/offerEdit";
        }

        offerAttribute.setId(id);
        offerService.edit(offerAttribute);

        return "redirect:/offer/list";
    }

    [snip]
}
```

The web page has this for its checkbox section. I use form:checkbox over form:checkboxes because I want to use a table,

```
[snip]
<form:form modelAttribute="offerAttribute" method="POST" action="${saveUrl}">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><form:hidden path="id" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="title">Title:</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="title" size="80" /></td>
            <td><form:errors path="title" cssClass="error" /></td>
        </tr>

    [snip]
    </table>

    <table>
    </table>

    <table>
        <c:forEach items="${offerAttribute.filters}" var="filter">
            <tr>
                <td><form:checkbox 
                        path="filters" 
                        label="${filter.text}" 
                        value="${filter.id}" 
                        checked="${filter.owned ? 'true' : ''}" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
    [snip]
```

The displayed web page has three filter checkboxes displayed, with just the middle checkbox filled in.

[image]

For the returned list, I expect the server to get only the middle checkbox, which is just what I want.

Here is what the generated checkboxes look like as source:

```
<table style="border: 1px solid; width: 100%; text-align:left;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input id="filters1" name="filters" type="checkbox" value="1"/>
                <label for="filters1">Adults (18+) desired, please</label>
                <input type="hidden" name="_filters" value="on"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input id="filters2" name="filters" checked="true" type="checkbox" value="2"/>
                <label for="filters2">Quiet audiences, please</label>
                <input type="hidden" name="_filters" value="on"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input id="filters3" name="filters" type="checkbox" value="4"/>
                <label for="filters3">Filter Text First</label>
                <input type="hidden" name="_filters" value="on"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

My checkbox is set, and in the HTML. To restate my question,

**Why doesn't the checkbox value get seen in the controller's POST handler?**

Thanks for any answers,

Jerome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of web research and different debugging sessions, I came up with a configuration I can live with.

In my controller I provide a model attribute of "filterList", containing List.  The "offerAttribute" is an Offer object, containing List filters.

The view has this sequence:

```
<table>
    <c:forEach items="${filterList}" var="filter" varStatus="status">
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="filters[${status.index}].id" 
                 value="${filter.id}"  
                 ${filter.owned ? 'checked' : ''} /> ${filter.text}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

When the POST is done the ownerAttribute.filters list is just as long as the original filterList object that created the checkboxes.  The checked ones contains a Filter.id value.  The unchecked ones contain a null.  (That is, the returned filters list is "sparse".)  If the user clicks on just a few checkboxes then I must parse the returned list to find those that were chosen.

Once I know the ID values of the checked-on filters, I fetch each of them through Hibernate, put them into my reconstructed Offer object and then persist them to the database.

I realize that I'm not (currently) using the form:checkbox.  But it works, and I'm pressed for time here.  I'll come back later, perhaps, and see what form:checkbox can do for me.

Answer (score 0):

The values of checkboxes could not be directly bind to List.

To get this working you need to create a simple pojo databean that will hold the values of your form fields in jsp. And in that databean to bind the values you need to declare `int[] filterId` and the values of your checkboxes will bind in that array.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: My Offer class seems to be the form for the page.  When I don't have the list of checkboxes I can add and update Offer objects to the DB.  My issue is with adding the list of checkboxes to the party.  I can add an int[] filterIds as a @Transient, making the checkboxes bind to filterIds and then dealing with the result through server code.  Is that what you're suggesting here?

Comment: Are you adding new checkboxed runtime using javascript??

Comment: In that case you need to use LazyList.